# Redirect user to thank you page

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, button

I have an html contact form and I would like to redirect the user to a thank you page after they click on the send button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disable click should be after the function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("buttonID").click(function(){
    window.location.href= 'http://google.com';
    })  
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the location of the window once your script is done saving:

```
location.href = 'my-thank-you-page.html'
```